# Evento OnKeyUp en Js con setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp

quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de hacer que unos 5 segundos despues que yo deje de teclear se ejecute cierto codigo, actualmente lo manejo en en evento keyUp, pero este es inmediato. ej: presiono la tecla A (quedo esperando 5 seg), pero luego de 1 seg vuelve a teclear, entonces vuelve a esperar otros 5 seg.

No se que tan posible sea esto

Comment: Es posible y bastante común. De hecho, existe ya alguna pregunta en el sitio para casos similares (aunque con otros tiempos más cortos, pero la idea es la misma). ¿Qué has buscado o investigado? ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Con qué errores o dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] donde encontrarás recomendaciones para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: como lo puedo buscar con que tematica

Comment: Aquí tienes una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/118823/250) que escribí para una pregunta parecida.